# Finding a correct way to augment shoes on user's foot

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit, coreml, apple-vision

What would be the best way to augement shoes on the user's feet?  Would you suggest ARKit's object detection or through the vision framework? Or is there any other better way to achieve this ? Thanks !

Answer (score -1):

ARkit+CoreML(To detect person's feet) will be best solution I guess. But you can try this amazing google framework for AR and analytic applications in real time [Mediapipe](https://github.com/google/mediapipe)

Comment: Mediapipe-Objectron is not available for iOS